# Append url with value of select option using php

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a select menu in jquery mobile that I want to show a table from another website when the user selects an option, but the table needs to change when the user selects a different option.

I am using simple HTML dom parser, but I was wondering how to add the value of the selected option on to the url so if the user selects an option with the value of 32, it adds 32 onto the url so that the url used in the PHP code would be 'http://www.generalconvention.org/gc/deputations?diocese_id=32'. How do I do this using PHP?

```
<?php
        include('simple_html_dom.php');

        // get DOM from URL or file
        $html = file_get_html('http://www.generalconvention.org/gc/deputations?diocese_id=');
        // Find all tables 
        foreach($html->find('table') as $element) 
        echo $element;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

After you capture the value, concatenate it like this:

```
<?php

        $value = "Your form value";

        include('simple_html_dom.php');

        // get DOM from URL or file
        $html = file_get_html('http://www.generalconvention.org/gc/deputations?diocese_id=' . $value);
        // Find all tables 
        foreach($html->find('table') as $element) 
        echo $element;
?>
```

Comment: But won't that only work for a static value? How do I set $value to the value of the selected option?

Answer (score 0):

You can do ajax call:

```
    $(".comboboxClass").change(function(){
        $("#divHtml").load('http://www.generalconvention.org/gc/deputations?diocese_id='+
$(this).find('option:selected').val()+' table.deputies'
        );
    });
```

In the `#divhtml` loads the contents of the table `.deputies` with  [load](https://api.jquery.com/load/) .